# Converting multiple lines of bash in to a single line

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any short and easy way to convert multiple lines of script in to a single line to be parsed in a eval command?

ie

```
getent group | cut -f3 -d":" | sort -n | uniq -c |\ 
 while read x ; do
     [ -z "${x}" ] && break
     set - $x     ;    if [ $1 -gt 1 ]; then
        grps=`getent group | nawk -F: '($3 == n) { print $1 }' n=$2 | xargs`       ;     echo "Duplicate GID ($2): ${grps}"  ;       fi      done
```

Comment: Usually, it is better to avoid `eval`.  (Some regard [`eval` as a misspelling of "evil."](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)).  What are you trying to do that makes `eval` seems like a good solution?

Comment: @john Hmm, this line is included in one of my txt file, which i use `read line` to get this command, then parse it through eval to get the result of the command.

Answer (score 0):

```
one_line=`cat your_script_file | sed ":a s/[\]$//; N; s/[\]$//; s/\n/ /; t a ;"`
echo $one_line
```